# ¿Cómo puedo crear una Aplicación Responsive en java?

Tags: java-swing

Necesito que mi sistema se adapte a cualquier tamaño que se le dé, he utilizado muchos Layout (o no se si es que no los se utilizar bien). Hay Layout que hacen que cambie según su resolución pero no es tan **"responsive"** que digamos, ya que cuando Maximizo la pantalla el orden de los componentes no quedan bien ubicados.

Tengo unos días investigando por todo internet y no encuentro la forma de que este se adapte al 100% en cualquier resolución. Recurro a ustedes para ver qué ayuda me pueden brindar.

¿Qué me recomiendan para que mi aplicación en Java pueda ser totalmente Responsive?

Comment: Java Swing no es lo mejor si buscas un diseño _responsive_ automático. Pero se puede conseguir con mucho tiempo y programación. Y sí, utilizar _layouts_ es el camino correcto, ya que hacen que los componentes se ajusten sin tener que poner coordenadas. Ahora bien, lo que buscas se consigue con mezcla de _layouts_ en paneles que están dentro de otros paneles con otros _layouts_. Revisa la documentación de [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) y piensa en las combinaciones que llevan al resultado que buscas, Quizá unos bocetos te ayudarían a encaminarte.

Comment: Muy cierto, lo he logrado utilizando muchos paneles dentro de otros, cada uno con un layout para que me permitiera hacer lo que deseo. Para esto se necesita mucha concentración y visión clara de lo que se desea para poder jugar con los Layout y los distintos Paneles. 
A pesar de que pude solucionarlo, tu respuesta es totalmente correcta. Gracias!